# Why does read() block and wait forever in parent process despite the writing end of pipe being closed?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, blocking

I'm writing a program with two processes that communicate through a pipe. The child process reads some parameters from the parent, executes a shell script with them and returns the results to the parent process line by line.

My code worked just fine until I wrote the `while(read())` part at the end of the parent process. The child would execute the shell script, read its echo's from `popen()` and print them to standard output.

Now I tried to write the results to the pipe as well and read them in the `while()` loop at the parent's end but it blocks and neither will the child process print the result to standard output. Apparently it won't even reach the point after reading the data from the pipe sent by the parent.

If I comment out the `while()` at the parent process, the child will print the results and return, and the program will end smoothly.

Why does the `while(read())` block even if I closed the writing end of the pipe in both parent and child processes?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int read_from_file(char **directory, int *octal) {
        FILE *file = fopen("input", "r");
        if (file == NULL) {
                perror("error opening file");
                exit(1);
        }
        fscanf(file, "%s %d", *directory, octal);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        char *directory = malloc(256);
        int *octal = malloc(sizeof *octal);

        pid_t pid;
        int pfd[2];
        char res[256];
        if (pipe(pfd) < 0) {
                perror("Error opening pipe");
                return 1;
        }

        if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
                perror("Error forking");

        if (pid == 0) {
                printf("client here\n");
                if (read(pfd[0], directory, 256) < 0)
                        perror("error reading from pipe");
                if (read(pfd[0], octal, sizeof(int)) < 0)
                        perror("error reading from pipe");
// This won't get printed:
                printf("client just read from pipe\n");
//              close(pfd[0]);

                char command[256] = "./asd.sh ";
                strcat(command, directory);
                char octal_c[5];
                sprintf(octal_c, " %d", *octal);
                strcat(command, octal_c);

                FILE *f = popen(command, "r");
                while (fgets(res, 256, f) != NULL) {
                        printf("%s", res);
                        if (write(pfd[1], res, 256) < 0)
                                perror("Error writing res to pipe");
                }
                fclose(f);
                close(pfd[1]);
                close(pfd[0]);
                fflush(stdout);
                return 1;
        }

        read_from_file(&directory, octal);

        if (write(pfd[1], directory, 256) < 0)
                perror("Error writing dir to pipe");
        if (write(pfd[1], octal, sizeof(int)) < 0)
                perror("error writing octal to pipe");

        int r;
        close(pfd[1]);

        while (r = read(pfd[0], res, 256)) {
                if (r > 0) {
                        printf("%s", res);
                }
        }
        close(pfd[0]);

        while (wait(NULL) != -1 || errno != ECHILD);
}
```

Comment: `read` returns -1 upon error, so your `while` loop would never terminate. You need to check for that case.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be what the question is directly about, but is the "This won't get printed" comment accurate?  That could easily be related to the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I get a "Client here" message and it blocks there, there is no "client just read from pipe" log printed. I think it must have to do with the pipes not being closed properly but I don't see what I'm doing wrong, because if I comment out the ```while()``` in the parent process (so that it never tries to read from the pipe), everything runs smoothly and gets printed, and then the program finishes.

Comment: @Thomas Could it be because the parent process tries to read the very message it printed to the pipe instead of letting the child read from it first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the child demonstrably reaches ...

> ```
>                 printf("client here\n");
> ```

... but seems not to reach ...

> ```
>                 printf("client just read from pipe\n");
> ```

... we can suppose that it blocks indefinitely on one of the two `read()` calls between.  With the right timing, that explains why the parent blocks on its own `read()` from the pipe.  But how and why does that blocking occur?

There are at least three significant semantic errors in your program:

1. pipes do not work well for bidirectional communication.  It is possible, for example, for a process to read back the bytes that it wrote itself and intended for a different process.  If you want bidirectional communication then use two pipes.  In your case, I think that would have avoided the apparent deadlock, though it would not, by itself, have made the program work correctly.
2. `write` and `read` do not necessarily transfer the full number of bytes requested, and short reads and writes are not considered erroneous.  On success, these functions return the number of bytes transferred, and if you want to be sure to transfer a specific number of bytes then you need to run the `read` or `write` in a loop, using the return values to track progress through the buffer being transferred.  Or use `fread()` and `fwrite()` instead.
3. Pipes convey undifferentiated streams of bytes.  That is, they are not message oriented.  It is not safe to assume that reads from a pipe will be paired with writes to the pipe, so that each read receives exactly the bytes written by one write.  Yet your code depends on that to happen.

Here's a plausible failure scenario that could explain your observations:

**The parent:**

1. `fork()`s the child.
2. after some time performs two writes to the pipe, one from variable `directory` and the other from variable `octal`.  At least the first of those is a short write.
3. closes its copy of the write end of the pipe.
4. blocks attempting to read from the pipe.

**The child:**

1. reads *all* the bytes written via its first read (into its copy of `directory`).
2. blocks on its second `read()`.  It can do this despite the parent closing its copy of the write end, because the write end of the pipe is still open in the child.

You then have a deadlock.  Both ends of the pipe are open in at least one process, the pipe is empty, and both processes are blocked trying to read bytes that can never arrive.

There are other possibilities that arrive at substantially the same place, too, some of them not relying on a short write.

Answer (score 0):

The parent process was trying to read from the pipe before the child could have read from it and write the results to it. Using two different pipes for the two-way communication solved the problem.